# See more/Add more rows in table angular

Tags: angular, button

Ive googled so much, but I cant figure out what Im not getting. I search for the example in the image below, but I can only find how to extend one particular row in the table.

I want to add more individual rows to the table when the "see more" btn is clicked from the API. Am I searching for the wrong thing, since I cant be able to find anything, or any packages that supports this? If so, what is it called that I cant be able to understand? Im using Angular as framework

[img of the table with the see more btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvOnQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know what is your code I imagine you has a table with data and some like

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
  <td>{{element.prop1}}</td>
  <td>{{element.prop2}}</td>
</tr>
```

Just can use [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) and a variable "page"

```
page:number=0 //<--declare variable in your .ts

<tr *ngFor="let element of elements |slice:0:(page*6)">
  <td>{{element.prop1}}</td>
  <td>{{element.prop2}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" *ngIf="page*6<elements.length>
    <button (click)="page=page+1">more</button>
  </td>
<tr>
```

If you has a table with values (really you should use tables only to show tabulated data) you can has a variable "more"

```
    more=false; //<--declare variable in your .ts

    <tr>
      <td>{{element.prop1}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{element.prop2}}</td>
    </tr>
    ....
    <tr>
      <td *ngIf="!more">
        <button (click)="more=true">more</button>
      </td>
    <ng-container *ngIf="more">
      <tr>
        <td>{{element.prop3}}</td>
      <tr>
      <td>
        <button (click)="more=false">less</button>
      </td>
   </ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was after. As for now I only have mock data, so the last approach worked great, but I will use the first approach as soon as I get the API data! How is it to add a "less" function to the first approach?

Comment: Sorry, really should be `slice:0:(page+1)*6`. Just use `<button (click)="page=0">`. NOTE For "simple functions" (e.g. equal a variable) it should prefer write in the own .html, else you can create a function in .ts.

Comment: Thank you so much! I hope I get to test it tomorrow :)